# Role description does not get updated

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am getting the role being created but the description does not get updated.

I have tried in two ways:

First:

```
Roles.CreateRole(model.RoleName);                      
using (tgpwebgedEntities context = new tgpwebgedEntities())
{
  var query = from r in context.aspnet_Roles where r.RoleName == r.RoleName select r;
   var obj = query.First();
   obj.Description = model.Description;
   context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Second:

```
using(tgpwebgedEntities context = new tgpwebgedEntities()) {
   var obj = context.aspnet_Roles.Single(r => r.RoleName == roleModel.RoleName);
   obj.Description = roleModel.Description;
   context.SaveChanges();
}
```

The curious thing is that this second way is the way I am using when the user is editing an aready created role using another action and works fine.

This first is used in a method that created the role and update its description since there is no support for description in .NET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your query statement,

```
var query = from r in context.aspnet_Roles where r.RoleName == r.RoleName select r;
```

"r.RoleName == r.RoleName" which will always be true and returns all entries. The query should be something similar to what you have in the second query

```
r => r.RoleName == roleModel.RoleName
```